# Using VBA Solver in Combination with Nested Loops

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large data set and some current VBA code to make some calculations. The code I have does the following:

1. It includes **two nested loops and copies and pastes** results of some equations in Excel into a large summary table.
2. Then the code **sorts the data and applies some advanced filters** with numerous criteria to arrive at a solution.

I'm wondering if it is possible to use VBA solver code to maximize my solution by varying the advanced filter criteria in combination with the current loops?  I have to manually iterate it at this point, but would like to be able to include solver to eliminate the manual iterations and determine the optimum filter criteria to maximize the solution.

I realize that the basic functionality of solver works great if I have a simple equation in Excel like `mx + b = c` and I want to maximize the value of `c` by varying `m` and `b`.  But I'm not sure if I can, or how to apply solver within my current loops? **My primary question is if anyone thinks VBA solver (or something similar) can be used for my application.**

If needed below is my current code, and beware that I'm self taught in VBA so my code is likely not the most efficient.

```
Sub Builder()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim UsedRng As Range
Dim FirstYr As Integer
Dim LastYr As Integer
Dim Counter1 As Single
Dim DeleteRow As Long

Windows("Model.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Full List").Select
Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

LastRow = UsedRng(UsedRng.Cells.Count).Row
Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("F1").Value = LastRow

FirstYr = Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("w5").Value
LastYr = Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("w6").Value

Windows("Portfolio.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Builder").Select
Range("A7:R23").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Windows("Model.xlsm").Activate
Counter1 = 0

For j = FirstYr To LastYr

    Sheets("Model").Range("o15").Value = j
    Sheets("Full List").Select
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ModelSummary").Select
    Cells(8, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Cells(6, 1).Value = j

    Sheets("Model").Select
    Range("H5:H24").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ModelSummary").Select
    Cells(7, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

    Cells(8, 1).Select

For i = 1 To (LastRow - 1)
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Model").Select
    Range("C3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("I6:I24").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ModelSummary").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
Next

Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(LastRow + 6, 20)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ModelSummary").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ModelSummary").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    Cells(7, 14), Cells(LastRow + 5, 14)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ModelSummary").Sort
    .SetRange Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(LastRow + 6, 20))
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

DeleteRow = Application.Match(Range("o1").Value, Range(Cells(8, 14), Cells(LastRow + 6, 14)), 0) + 7
Range(Cells(DeleteRow, 1), Cells(LastRow + 6, 20)).Clear

Windows("Model.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("ModelSummary").Select
Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(LastRow + 6, 20)).Select
Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(LastRow + 6, 20)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("E2:T3"), Unique:=False
Range("A6").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Portfolio.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Builder").Select
Cells(7, 1 + Counter1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("Model.xlsm").Activate
Range("A6").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(LastRow + 6, 20)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Counter1 = Counter1 + 1

Next

Windows("Portfolio.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Builder").Select
Range("S2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Summary").Select
Range("A3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried turning on "Record Macro" do what you want to do with the solver, then looking at the code? I have never done this, but if Record macro, records something I would start there.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution that you are trying to maximize is a spreadsheet cell that depends on the contents of the criteria range then, sure, you can use the Solver to try to find optimal settings for those ranges. If the dependence isn't linear then you are unlikely to find a global optimum, but Excel's Solver now includes an evolutionary algorithm which can handle highly non-linear functional relationships. The solver can be controlled by VBA. In addition to various online tutorials that you can easily find, I recommend the book "VBA for Modelers" by S. Christian Albright ( [http://www.amazon.com/VBA-Modelers-Developing-Decision-Microsoft/dp/1285869613/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1285869613)). It is one of the few books I know of that covers in depth using VBA to automate the solver. It even has a chapter on using VBA in portfolio optimization (which seems to be the sort of thing that you are doing).

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  John, I'll check out that book on Amazon.  The solution cell DOES depend on the criteria range, however it is NOT directly linked via excel equations and formulas.  It is only linked based on the criteria/filters that are applied to the results table that then provide various solutions.  That said, do you think I may have a chance of getting some solver code to work?

Comment: Rather than filtering -- you could perhaps use a column of 0-1 variables and functions like SUMPRODUCT if you need to select some but not all potential investments (or whatever you are trying to do). You can often mimic the functionality of filters with binary decision variables, and this sort of move might be needed if you want to use the built-in solver.